# Splitting lists at the commas

Tags: python, list

Currently I have a long list that has elements like this: 
['01/01/2013 06:31, long string of characters,Unknown'].

How would I split each element into:
['01/01/2013 06:31], [long string of characters],[Unknown]? Can I even do that?

I tried variable.split(","), but I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'".

Here's my code:

```
def sentiment_analysis():
    f = open('C:\path', 'r')
    write_to_list = f.readlines()
    write_to_list = map(lambda write_to_list: write_to_list.strip(), write_to_list)
    [e.split(',') for e in write_to_list]
    print write_to_list[0:2]
    f.close()
    return
```

I'm still not getting it, I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to do `split` for string, i.e. `variable[0].split(",")`. Or for list with strings you could do `[s.split(',') for s in variable]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You are given this:

`['01/01/2013 06:31, long string of characters,Unknown']`

Alright. If you know that there is only this one long string in this list, just extract the only element:

```
>>> x = ['01/01/2013 06:31, long string of characters,Unknown']
>>>
>>> y = x[0].split(",")  # extract only element and split by comma
>>> print(y)  # list of strings, with one depth
['01/01/2013 06:31', ' long string of characters', 'Unknown']
```

Now for whatever reasons, you actually want each eletent of the outer list to be a list with one string in it. That is easy enough to do - simply use `map` and anonymous functions:

```
...  # continuation from snippet above
...
>>> z = map(lambda s: [s], y)  # encapsulates each elem of y in a list
>>> print(z)
[['01/01/2013 06:31'], [' long string of characters'], ['Unknown']]
```

There you have it.

---

## One-Liner Conclusion

No list comprehensions, no `for` loops, no generators. Just really simple functional programming and anonymous functions.

*Given original list `l`,*

```
res = map(lambda s: [s],
          l[0].split(","))
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension!

```
>>> variable = ['01/01/2013 06:31, long string of characters,Unknown']
>>> [x.split(',') for x in variable]
[['01/01/2013 06:31', ' long string of characters', 'Unknown']]
```

But wait, that's nested more than you wanted...

```
>>> itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split(',') for x in variable)
<itertools.chain object at 0x109180fd0>
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split(',') for x in variable))
['01/01/2013 06:31', ' long string of characters', 'Unknown']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I'm looking for 3 different lists from one list.[ ['01/01/2013 06:31]', [' long string of characters'], ['Unknown']]. Thanks!

Comment: That's as simple as putting square brackets around `x.split(',')`